# Itextsharp - Nombre del PDF dependiendo de variable

Tags: c#, pdf, itextsharp, itext

actualmente tengo un codigo con iText para crear PDF con una direccion fija en este caso:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("C:/Atreus-Export/presupuesto.pdf", FileMode.Create));
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer que el nombre del PDF dependa de una variable.
He probado con:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("C:/Atreus-Export/" + tb_name + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
```

Pero me salta error al crearlo:

> System.NotSupportedException: "No se admite el formato proporcionado de la ruta de acceso"

Answer (score 1):

Creo que a mí me pasó lo mismo. Lo que tienes que hacer es armar primero la cadena y guardarla en una variable String. Y luego usas esa variable como parámetro de FileStream. No se porqué pero si lo haces como ahora el sistema se confunde con los espacios, comillas, etc...

```
pdfName = "C:/Atreus-Export/" + tb_name + ".pdf"

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pdfName, FileMode.Create));
```

Comment: Me salta el mismo error.

Comment: Pudiste solucionar? Prueba poner el PDF en la raíz del disco C para descartar que el problema sea con la ruta al directorio

Comment: No lo conseguí arreglar. Y ya probé eso y nada igual.

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que por iTextSharp guardes el archivo con un nombre fijo y luego lo renombres a nivel de SO.

Comment: ¿Y como hago eso?

Comment: pdfName = "C:/temporal.pdf" y luego

System.IO.File.Move(C:/temporal.pdf", "pdfname");

donde "pdfname" es la cadena que armas tú mismo.

La sintaxis real del comando es:
System.IO.File.Move("oldfilename", "newfilename");

Tienes que usar 
using System.IO;

Al inicio del programa